Selenium C# Nested Loop
I have an HTML TABLE that displays roughly 20 true/false questions on each page. I have a loop running to randomly answer each question. Once the questions are completed on the page, a button is popped to proceed to the next page. There are probably 20 pages though. Rather than repeat the same step over and over (specflow), I would like to create a nested loop but I have not been able to get it working.
An example of what I have tried. This will increment the TR so it lands on each question and randomly answers. I have then tried to do a bool on an element to see if the next questions are there but I am getting lost on the nested loop so that it iterates through all pages. Suggestions?
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    var rand = Faker.RandomNumber.Next(0, 1).ToString();
    if (rand == "0")
    {
        Browser.FindElement_byXPath(string.Format("//table[@class='table']//tr[{0}]//td[@class='classy']/label/input[@value= 'T']", i + 1)).Click();
    }
    else
    {
        Browser.FindElement_byXPath(string.Format("//table[@class='table']//tr[{0}]//td[@class='classy']/label/input[@value= 'F']", i + 1)).Click();
    }
}

then continue to the next page
HTML
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="myClass">
            <td>1. </td>
            <td>I Like Ducks? </td>
            <td class="classy">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="T" checked="checked"> True</label>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="F"> False</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="myClass">
            <td>2. </td>
            <td>I Like Cars? </td>
            <td class="classy">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="Q2" value="T"> True</label>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="Q2" value="F"> False</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right"> Continue 
    <span class="classless"></span>
</button>


I don't supposed you can share the URL to one of the pages? I'd like to see it to get a better idea of how the page is structured so I can write some code to test it.

Given the HTML you provided, I would write it like this...
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
driver.Url = "<the url>";

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
Random random = new Random();

int numberOfPages = 20; // ideally this would be counted from something on the page instead of hard coded
for (int pageIndex = 0; pageIndex < numberOfPages; pageIndex++)
{
    IWebElement table = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector("table.table")));
    ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> questions = table.FindElements(By.CssSelector("tbody > tr.myClass"));
    foreach (IWebElement question in questions)
    {
        string value = random.Next(2) == 0 ? "T" : "F";
        question.FindElement(By.CssSelector($"input[value='{value}']")).Click();
    }

    if (pageIndex != numberOfPages)
    {
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("button.btn-primary")).Click();
    }
}


Some feedback...

I'm not familiar with Faker.RandomNumber so I just used the standard Random.
Don't put your Random declaration inside the loop... it's likely to cause issues generating random numbers.
Rather than hard coding a number/count, I would suggest that you get a count of the questions from the page and then loop through them. That way your count is always right, no matter how much the number of questions vary from page to page.
There's this programming principle called "DRY" aka Don't repeat yourself. While you didn't technically repeat yourself in the T v F case, 99.9% of the code is the same so I pulled out code determining whether the random number means it's "T" or "F" into its own line and assigned "T" or "F" to value. I can then insert value into my CSS selector and click it to choose T/F.

I tested this code on the HTML you provided and it's choosing a random value for both questions and clicking the "Continue" button successfully.

Thanks Jeff. How would I carry this loop to the next page so it is just a continuous loop vs calling the method 15- 20 times?  Once you click next, it would need to be invoked again.

I updated my answer to show a same loop for pages

Thanks agin Jeff. Yeah there is nothing coded to deterermine how many pages are remaining so this works well!

One thing you could do is continue until you don't detect the "Continue" button and then exit the loop.
